# How do I write an iterative version of my recursive function?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, signal-processing, interpolation

I have a function that takes a large array of long doubles (65536 elements) and performs a bunch of mathematical operations to each element which ends up with a modified array which is then returned to main.

The problem is, it is recursive and with so many elements, the program and the computer eventually crashes which I can only assume is because of a stack overflow(!). The code for the recursive function is given below:

```
long double *sift(long double *signal){
   int i, def;
   double maxsize, minsize;
   int *max,*min;
   long double *maxinterp, *mininterp,*upenv,*loenv,*protoimf;

   max = maxArray(signal, ARRAYSIZE); //build binary array indicating 
   min = minArray(signal, ARRAYSIZE); //maxima or minima at that index

   maxsize = count(max, ARRAYSIZE); //count total max/minima
   minsize = count(min, ARRAYSIZE);

   def = checkDefinition(signal, maxsize+minsize); 
   if(def>0) {          //checks if signal has equal number of zero
       return signal;   //crossings and extrema
   }

   maxinterp = gslMax(signal, maxsize, ARRAYSIZE); //gnu scientific lib
   mininterp = gslMin(signal, minsize, ARRAYSIZE); //cubic spline interp.

   upenv = envelope(maxinterp, max, min, maxsize, minsize); //envelopes of
   loenv = envelope(mininterp, min, max, minsize, maxsize); //signal

   protoimf = imf(signal, upenv, loenv); //find mean curve 
   protoimf = sift(protoimf);            //recursive call till definition
                                         //is satisfied
   if (def > 0) {
      return protoimf;
   }

   //free(min); free(upenv) etc. 

   return protoimf;
}
```

I tried to go the iterative route by calling sift() in main in a while loop (with the recursion edited out ofc) with checkDefinition() as the condition. However, I am not getting the same array back compared to recursion. My helper function countExtrema() calls both max/minarray() and count() and returns the number of extrema in the array passed in. However the value differs than when I do recursion (which gives the correct output/behavior).

I think it is because I need to store the local variables somehow? I've researched online and it seems I need a stack maybe? Can someone guide me on how to replicate my recursive function in c?

Below is code for my imf function:

```
long double *imf(long double *hilbert, long double *upper, long double *lower){
   int i;
   long double *imf = malloc(sizeof(long double)*ARRAYSIZE);   //253
   for(i=0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++){
      imf[i] = upper[i] + lower[i];
      imf[i] = imf[i] / 2.0000000000;
   }
   for(i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++){
      imf[i] = hilbert[i] - imf[i];
   }
   return imf;

}
```

And here is the complaint from valgrind:

```
15,728,400 bytes in 15 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 14 of 15
==10394==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10394==    by 0x401C68: imf (sift.c:253)
==10394==    by 0x402472: sift (sift.c:337)
==10394==    by 0x402626: main (sift.c:423)
```

There are many more complaints with functions such as envelope() 
and gslMin() but they all have the same structure where I allocate some memory and return the pointer to that memory. The problem is if I move my free statements to within the while loop in sift() I get seg fault. How do I go about fixing this memory leak?

Comment: Plus one for making me laugh @jeffamaphone.
Regardless, please edit and provide the code in which you attempt to make it iterative.

Comment: See [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/273651/40065)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of memory allocation completely.  Here is a simplified version of the `imf` function:

```
void imf(long double *hilbert, long double *upper, long double *lower) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        hilbert[i] -= (upper[i] + lower[i]) / 2.0;
}
```

`sift` can be simplified too.  It will modify the `signal` array in place, iteratively.

```
long double *sift(long double *signal) {
    int i, def;
    double maxsize, minsize;
    int *max, *min;
    long double *maxinterp, *mininterp, *upenv, *loenv;

    for (;;) {
        max = maxArray(signal, ARRAYSIZE); //build binary array indicating 
        min = minArray(signal, ARRAYSIZE); //maxima or minima at that index

        maxsize = count(max, ARRAYSIZE); //count total max/minima
        minsize = count(min, ARRAYSIZE);

        def = checkDefinition(signal, maxsize + minsize); 
        if (def > 0) {       //checks if signal has equal number of zero
            return signal;   //crossings and extrema
        }

        maxinterp = gslMax(signal, maxsize, ARRAYSIZE); //gnu scientific lib
        mininterp = gslMin(signal, minsize, ARRAYSIZE); //cubic spline interp.

        upenv = envelope(maxinterp, max, min, maxsize, minsize); //envelopes of
        loenv = envelope(mininterp, min, max, minsize, maxsize); //signal

        imf(signal, upenv, loenv); //find mean curve 
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought recursion was the problem but after running valgrind it appears I am leaking a lot of memory. I have tried uncommenting the free(signal) line but it doesn't help. I calloc in max/minarray() and gslmax/min() and a bunch of other functions and I free it after the for(;;) loop in sift(). Obviously this is wrong but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Since we don't see how you allocate all this, we cannot help.  publish more code.

Comment: I've edited the OP. If you could take a look I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Deep recursion is a bad sign. You should inspect your algorithm more thoroughly.
2. It's possible to tranform any recursive algorithm into iterative one, using "stack-like" array to store "recursion context". Needless to say, that array can be as large as free RAM. See, for example, quick-sort iterative implementation - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-quick-sort

Comment: This is a bold claim! For the OP's code, turning recusion into an iteration is quite simple and does not require any extra data.  For the Ackerman function, getting rid of recursion is a real challenge. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#C

Comment: Inefficient, but still possible. But Ackerman function is hard to compute for large N, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that in:

```
if (def > 0) {
  return protoimf;
}
//free memory
```

def is never > 0 because that has been checked some lines earlier. Then, if you can move the "free memory" part to before `protoimf = sift(protoimf);` you are left with tail recursion, which a proper compiler can optimize to avoid the recursion actually being performed. The last line of the function then becomes:

```
    return(sift(protoimf));
}
```

Comment: not all compilers optimize tail recursion, nor is it a requirement of the C Standard.  This is not lisp ;-)